# Global minimum and maximum

Tags: calculus

Given the function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2}.$$

Local min: $(-1;0)$
Local max: $(1;0)$

How to prove that $(-1;0)$ is a global minimum and $(1;0)$ is a global maximum?

Comment: Have you tried finding the derivative of $f$ and perform first, second derivative test? Also, is $f$ a $f(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Yes. This helps to find local min and local max.

Comment: It helps to find all the max and min points except at the boundaries. You only need to check by evaluating the function whether its local or global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(1,0)=1/2,f(-1,0)=-1/2,$ just note
$$1/2-f(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)^2+y^2}{2x^2+2y^2+2}.$$
Also $$f(x,y)-(-1/2)=\frac{(x+1)^2+y^2}{2x^2+2y^2+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks. However, how can I conclude from this that (1;0) is global max and (-1;0) is global min?

Comment: @Pichen'ka: $z^2\geq 0$.

Comment: @Pichen'ka We want e.g. $f(x,y)\le 1/2$ for all $x,y.$ That is, $(1/2)-f(x,y) \ge 0.$ The fraction on the right of the first calculation is $\ge 0$ because each of the terms, including $(x-1)^2,$ in the right side is nonnegative, since it is the square of a real number. [also in top and bottom there are no negative coefficients.] Similar for the min.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.: The AM-GM inequality is enough.
$$\frac{|x|}{1+x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{2},$$
with equality attained at $y=0$ and $|x|=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really believe that this is the way of solving this problem. However, can you explain how did you come to such an inequality? How did you find |x|/(1+x^2)? How did you compared this with 1/2?

Comment: @Pichen'ka: $y^2\geq 0$ is trivial and $1+x^2\geq 2|x|$ follows from the AM-GM inequality. To me, it was just the most natural approach.

Comment: thanks a lot for solving this problem))))

Answer (score 0):

If you can show that $f(x,y)\to0$ as $x^2+y^2\to\infty$, then you can pick $R$ so large that $|f(x,y)|<0.0001$ whenever $x^2+y^2>R$.  Then you can say that since $f(x,y)$ is a **continuous** function of $(x,y)$ on the **compact** set $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \le R\}$, it must have an absolute maximum and an absolute minimum on that set, and since it's differentiable everywhere, those must occur where the partial derivatives are $0$. And the maximum and minimum values on that set must be far bigger than any values at points not in that set, since the latter do not exceed $0.0001$ in absolute value.